# Xcode runs the older version of project

Tags: ios, xcode, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to deploy my application on my iPad but at each time Xcode deploys a previous version of the app and doesn't deploy the new one with the modifications I made. I tried cleaning the project, deleting the related folders in `~/Library/Application Support/` but it did change anything.

Comment: Your tag mentions that you're doing something hybrid? Which platform are you using? Maybe the platform is doing something shady. I have never had Xcode not build / run / archive the current version of my code on a native app..

Comment: I'm using cordova framework and I tried to remove and add the ios platform but it didnt change anything neither

Comment: show us your organizer screen.

Comment: no crushes, no archives

Comment: Read [ask] and [faq]. SO is not a forum so do not put tags in the title of your question. Also, use proper grammar and spelling.

Comment: Have you found a solution ? I'm having the same problem. Even changed the branch to an older version and the output from console are from files that does not exists on the current branch wtff